# Need to make a Publisher-Subscriber using Java RMI

Tags: java, rmi, publish-subscribe

Does anyone have an implementation of a Publish-Subscribe for Java RMI? Or even a tutorial that I can follow?

Answer (score 3):

This is usually done with [Java JMS topics](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=26137&seqNum=5), not RMI.  Is RMI a requirement or a poor technology choice?

Comment: My teacher told me to implement it using Java RMI, but I don't think this is a strong requirement. Thanks a lot for pointing out JAVA JMS. Do you have any tutorial at hand for a PubSub using Java JMS?

Comment: I have to make a decoupled middleware using publish subscripe mechanics. By now I use Java RMI, should I change to JMS for that purpose?

Comment: RMI is not publish subscribe; it's synchronous.  This question is five years old.  Don't hijack old questions.